# Does extending a base class and both classes having @Id annotation cause Repeated column in mapping for entity?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two classes. 
One class extends the other. 
Both classes will be persisted in the database. 
Why am I still getting : Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.ct.www.model.Bt column: q_Id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Questions.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Questions")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class Questions implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //@Access(value= AccessType.FIELD)
    private String q_Id;

    @Column(name="q_type")
    private String q_Type;

    @Column(name="q_lang")
    private String q_lang;

    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getQ_Type() {
        return q_Type;
    }

    public void setQ_Type(String q_Type) {
        this.q_Type = q_Type;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="q_Id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getQ_Id() {
        return q_Id;
    }

    public void setQ_Id(String q_Id) {
        this.q_Id = q_Id;
    }

    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getQ_lang() {
        return q_lang;
    }

    public void setQ_lang(String q_lang) {
        this.q_lang = q_lang;
    }

}
```

BT.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BT")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class BT extends Questions implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
//  @Id 
//  @Column(name="q_Id")
    private String q_Id;

    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getQ_Id() {
        return q_Id;
    }

    public void setQ_Id(String q_Id) {
        this.q_Id = q_Id;
    }

//  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
//  @JoinColumn(name="q_id")
//  @MapsId
    private Questions question;

    public Questions getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Questions question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
}
```

One of my use case is 
Questions and BT will be persisted separately into corresponding tables in MySQL (Questions table and BT table).
BT is a type of Question. So I decided to extend it.
Both table has a primary key which is Id, and my DAO class will first insert in Questions table and use same Id for BT class which later inserts into BT table.

Answer (score 1):

Extending a base class which is an `Entity` will cause this problem.

You can:

- Remove the common mapped fields/properties from the child class
- Add `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` above parent class for your use case.

Refer to [**Section 2.11.4 in Hibernate-5.3.1.Final User Guide**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-table-per-class) for example code.

If you need different generation strategy in parent and child, you can override the `getQ_Id()` method in child and implement that.

Comment: But both entities are mapped to separate tables.

Comment: @user3705478: That is why you need to use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`